# Renesas CS+ for CC vs for CA, CX vs e2 studio

Tags: ide, renesas

I just get started with renesas MCU: RL78 - D1A – R5F10DPJJFB.  I went to Renesas website and saw different IDEs: CS+ for CC, CS+ for CA, CX, e2 studio so I would like to ask what is the differences between them? Pros and cons of each IDE and which one will be most suitable for me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CC is Renesas' new universal compiler that works with most of the latest-generation parts. CA and CX are legacy compilers. Due to some changes in compiler features, intrinsics, etc., separate CS+ installs have been created so that the help files and compiler interfaces did not suffer under the burden of legacy support.

There are some devices that are only supported under the legacy compilers, but if you're using a device from the current lineup (RL78, RX, RH850, etc.) then CC is the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

The main thing to know is e2 studio is for the American market and CS+ is "else."  If you expect support to help you, I recommend sticking with that.

I personally hate how Renesas does that, but otherwise love their products.

By the way, when you get started, check out their "Applilet" (aka Code Generator, AP4, and I think even a few other names that I forget offhand) but it's actually a really cool utility for driver generation. It will generate all your peripheral setup code for you in minutes and allow you to get right to your application code. If you've never used it, find and go through a tutorial on it first. There are some on Renesas website and the rest of the Web.

I am using it for RL78 to great success.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how about CC version vs CA, CX version? What are the differences between them and which one are you using?